# How to install box-cutter/centos72 using vagrant on virtualbox

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, centos7, vagrant-windows

But I am getting while downloading vagrant box
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Box 'box-cutter/centos72' could not be found. Attempting to find and install...
    default: Box Provider: virtualbox
    default: Box Version: >= 0
The box 'box-cutter/centos72' could not be found or
could not be accessed in the remote catalog. If this is a private
box on HashiCorp's Vagrant Cloud, please verify you're logged in via
`vagrant login`. Also, please double-check the name. The expanded
URL and error message are shown below:

URL: ["https://vagrantcloud.com/box-cutter/centos72"]
Error: Could not resolve proxy: cdn.boxcutter.io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dNQ9.png)

Comment: Do you set that proxy intentionally ?

Comment: Please never post error messages as images

Comment: How do i set proxy ? Ok I will not upload pics again

Comment: Please tell me solution for this problem